# Using QProcess with only arguments

Tags: c++, qt, compilation, g++, qprocess

I am trying to compile another .cpp code with QProcess. I use this code in my program.

```
QStringList arguments;
arguments << "g++";
arguments << "-o";
arguments << QDir::toNativeSeparators(exePath);   //path and exe path to future .exe
arguments << QDir::toNativeSeparators(mainPath);  // path to main.cpp

QProcess process;
process.open();

process.setArguments(arguments);

process.start();
process.waitForFinished();

process.close();
```

It works and it compile another .cpp file and create .exe fot that tested project.
But I also get warning:

QProcess::start: program not set

But I dont want to set program...In the beginning I was using std::system() for this but I would like to use Qt libraries.

Do you know how to surpass warning ?

And again: This is program which is compiling totally different main.cpp from totally different program.

Comment: `I dont want to set program` what do you mean, the program is visibly g++

Comment: Note that [`QProcess::open`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#open) `"Starts the program set by setProgram() with arguments set by setArguments()"`, so you effectively call `start` twice in the code shown -- the first time without any program *or* argumants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I dont want to set program

as I can see you want to use `g++` and that one is the program

so

```
QStringList arguments;

arguments << "-o";
arguments << QDir::toNativeSeparators(exePath);   //path and exe path to future .exe
arguments << QDir::toNativeSeparators(mainPath);  // path to main.cpp

QProcess process;

process.start("g++", arguments);
process.waitForFinished();
```

or

```
QStringList arguments;

arguments << "-o";
arguments << QDir::toNativeSeparators(exePath);   //path and exe path to future .exe
arguments << QDir::toNativeSeparators(mainPath);  // path to main.cpp

QProcess process;

process.setProgram("g++");
process.setArguments(arguments);
process.start();
process.waitForFinished();
```

Comment: Result is same. It works same as my solution but stil getting warning 

QProcess::start: program not set

Comment: @MatejPeluha I iedited my answer, try the second proposal, but for me both must work, are you sure you did as I said ?

Comment: Still same result.

Comment: @MatejPeluha did you removed the call to open ?

Comment: Oooohhhh, I am feeling little bit stupid now....sorry...Yes without open/close its working.

Thank you very much !!!

Comment: @MatejPeluha that happens a day to all of us ;-)

Answer (score 1):

> Do you know how to surpass warning ?

Use the `setProgram()` function:

```
QProcess p;
//set the program
p.setProgram("g++");

//create args
QStringList arguments = {
  "-o",
  QDir::toNativeSeparators(exePath),
  QDir::toNativeSeparators(mainPath) 
};

//set the args
p.setArguments(arguments);
```

Additionally, don't use both `open()` and `start()`. From the [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#open):

> This method is an alias for start(), and exists only to fully implement the interface defined by QIODevice.

So just `process.start()` is enough.